# How fix bug in interface builder xcode 8.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

[image]

I have this error with storyboards after update to 8.1 today.

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this?

Comment: @Yaroslav yes. Simple reboot your machine.

Comment: Sadly, reboot didn't do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

1. Clean the Xcode project
2. Quit the xcode
3. Clean all the contents in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData manually.

Answer (score 0):

I would double check the properties on the canvas, maybe too many settings are enabled, and they are conflicting with each other.

[image]